# handling multi-indexing in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Consider a the data in following way where ProductId and Date are indexes. I used the following code

```
>>> df = df.set_index('Date').groupby('productID').resample('W').sum()

                   Sales
productID   Date    
1000    01/01/2017  10
        01/08/2017  15
        01/15/2017  64
        01/22/2017  21
        01/29/2017  21
1001    01/01/2017  15
        01/08/2017  54
        01/15/2017  51
        01/22/2017  19
        01/29/2017  56
```

I want to pivot the results in the following way

```
                                 Sales              
productID   01/01/2017  01/08/2017  01/15/2017  01/22/2017  01/29/2017
1000           10          15         64           21         21
1001           15          54         51           19         56
```

I am trying to do this by using the pivot function in Pandas

```
df = df.pivot(index='ProductID', columns='Date', values='Sales')
```

but it returns the following error

```
ValueError: cannot insert ProductID, already exists
```

Please guide me how can I transform the results in the given way. Thanks

Comment: So problem is add `Sales` and create `MultiIndex` in columns?

Comment: The problem is I have multiindex columns which was returned to me by the code I just edit and not I want to get the data in the above mentioned form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add `['Sales']` for convert to `Series` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby('productID').resample('W')['Sales'].sum().unstack(1)
#same as
#df = df.set_index('Date').groupby('productID').resample('W').sum()['Sales'].unstack(1)


print (df)
Date       01/01/2017  01/08/2017  01/15/2017  01/22/2017  01/29/2017
productID                                                            
1000               10          15          64          21          21
1001               15          54          51          19          56
```

Comment: Maybe a few words about `1` - it means get second (python counts from 0) level (dates) and create columns from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [98]: df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns='Date', values='Sales', aggfunc='sum')
Out[98]:
Date       01/01/2017  01/08/2017  01/15/2017  01/22/2017  01/29/2017
productID
1000               10          15          64          21          21
1001               15          54          51          19          56
```

Comment: Please see I have made the edit to make it more understandable. I have already indexed the columns but now I want to make one index as it is and the other index 'Date' to be pivoted in the column